# CloudException: No suitable cloud connector found

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

My project has dependencies on `spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors` and `spring-cloud-localconfig-connector`. Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public CloudFactory cloudFactory() {
        CloudFactory cf = new CloudFactory();
        cf.registerCloudConnector(new LocalConfigConnector());
        return cf;
    }

}

@Component
class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    CloudFactory cf;

    @EventListener(value = ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void postConstruct() {
        Cloud cloud = cf.getCloud();
    }

}
```

When I try to run the above code locally, I get an exception saying:

> org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable cloud connector found

Although, the parent's version is irrelevant but I am using `2.1.8.RELEASE`.

Can someone point out what's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the default datasource:

```
mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/databasename
```

You can set it using the run configuration or create a seperate `properties` file for it.